# Run Python script on startup as root

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, root, boot

I wrote a python program that I want to execute on boot, but it HAS to be executed as root, and I don't know how.
What are the things I need to do to achieve this? Where should I put the file(the script is in a folder with the necessary python packages) so it runs on boot?
How do I run the file as root? Whether it is to put the python folder in a certain directory, use another script to execute the python script, or another way, please share your solutions!
I'm doing it on a Raspberry Pi, so the OS is Linux.

Comment: Check this out: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=134401

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way is to [create a systemd service](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/systemd.md) that might look like:

```
[Unit]
Description=Some python script
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 script.py
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/scriptdir
StandardOutput=inherit
StandardError=inherit
Restart=always
User=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You should save this in `/etc/systemd/system/servicename.service` where `servicename` can be anything, then set it to run on startup with `sudo systemctl enable servicename.service`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Aplet123. Although it runs at startup, I think it still doesn't run as root. How to achieve this?

Comment: What makes you think that? Systemd should be running it as root.